# Generating a flagging variable based on another variable in r

Tags: r, recode

I am trying to generate a flagging variable. here how my sample dataset looks like:

```
data <- data.frame(
  ids = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3),
  cat = c("A","B","B", "C","B","C", "A","B","A"))

> data
  ids cat
1   1   A
2   1   B
3   1   B
4   2   C
5   2   B
6   2   C
7   3   A
8   3   B
9   3   A
```

I need a flagging variable that flags the `ids` if there is no `C` observed for each `id`.

```
 > data
      ids cat  flag
    1   1   A    0
    2   1   B    0
    3   1   B    0
    4   2   C    1
    5   2   B    1
    6   2   C    1
    7   3   A    0
    8   3   B    0
    9   3   A    0
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Here's a base R solution: `data$flag <- as.integer(data$cat %in% "C")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'ids', create the 'flag' by checking if 'C' is `%in%` 'cat', returns a logical value of TRUE/FALSE, coerced to 1/0 with `as.integer` or `+`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(ids) %>%
     mutate(flag = +('C' %in% cat))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ids [3]
#    ids cat    flag
#  <dbl> <fct> <int>
#1     1 A         0
#2     1 B         0
#3     1 B         0
#4     2 C         1
#5     2 B         1
#6     2 C         1
#7     3 A         0
#8     3 B         0
#9     3 A         0
```

Or wrap with `any`

```
  ... %>%
  mutate(flag = as.integer(any(cat %in% 'C')))
```